# Use alternative layout when there's not enough space

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `RelativeLayout` that has a number of controls in it. On some screens, there might not be enough room for this layout as well as the other screen elements. In this case, I'd like to use an alternate layout that excludes some controls and has less padding.

How can I implement this in a performant manner? The smaller layout should only be loaded if the larger layout definitely won't fit. I don't want to use the various [screen size qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers) because whether the layout will fit is a function of the width and height of the screen and the additional visible controls and that seems like it will get too complicated.

Comment: do you know what is the minimum size (height and width in px or dp) you need for doing the full layout?

Comment: I don't know the exact height. There's a number of controls including some text views (measured in sp), which complicate determining an exact height. Also, I'd rather leave the measuring and laying out to the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I Personally think you should use the new screen size qualifiers**. It's how Android is designed and I think you should follow those rules. It will very probably also make the whole development process a lot easier!

---

But if you insist on doing it yourself, the only way I can think of to "hardcode" it, would be something like this:

**Step 1: obtain the screen size**

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

or if you're targeting a lower API level:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
```

**Step 2: pick an alternative layout depending on the screen size**

```
if(width < value_x_small && height < value_y_small){
        setContentView(R.layout.main_small);

} else if(width > value_x_small && height > value_y_small){
        setContentView(R.layout.main_large);

} else {
        setContentView(R.layout.main_larged);

}
```

This code allows you to select your own resources depending on the screen size in px. Its probably better to convert the px values to DP (DPI) and use those to make your decisions.You might also want to add a check on the current screen orientation.

Comment: You're right, using the screen size qualifiers is a better idea. In the `onMeasure` method, I can detect that I should use the smaller layout, but at that point there's nothing I can do to change it. With the screen size qualifier, it could be the case that I suboptimally choose the smaller layout, but that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your controls as separate `Fragments` and position them depending on screen size. Here is more info about [Fragments and their Design Philosophy](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) .

Comment: I'm aware of fragments. This question is about views and layouts.